# ASP.NET MVC Async - Is EntityFramework Query CPU-bound or Network-bound or I/O-bound

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

Is it worthwhile to use Task based Asynch action methods in an ASP.NET MVC project to retrieve a bunch of EntityFramework queries which use LINQ-to-EF.  The website is hosted in Azure as is the database.  There are quite a few queries that load up a bunch of arrays to send via JSON to an ajax call from the client.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, and slapping `async` on your action methods isn't magically going to improve performance.

Comment: what is the right question

Comment: That depends on your actual problem, which you didn't explain. Answering _"Is EntityFramework Query CPU-bound or Network-bound or I/O-bound"_ isn't very likely to be of help.

Comment: There is no problem.  I just want to make my website scale better.  The performance is already good.  I can always add more resources on Azure, but I want to make the best use of what I got already.  I do not see how  that is not reasonable to ask.  Yes it is general, and will depend on my circumstances but I am not about to show the whole website.

Comment: The major factor is always the way you query the database, how do you write actual queries, what indexes you have in the database, are tables strongly normalized or not etc. You can often speed up the data layer just by optimizing the way you query it, no matter if you use EF or anything else.

Comment: Well I am not a db admin, but I have done alot of indexing to improve performance, as well as used stored procedures to get data for the Entities.  But thanks for pointing that out and trying to be helpful. I am just looking to find out if it is worth it.  It seems perhaps not, but why then would EF6 have all the async methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is worthwhile as long as you are using truly async api (such as EntityFramework async methods) and not creating an async wrappers for example by wrapping your synchronous core in `Task.Run` or `Task.FromResult`.
Asynchronous method doesn't suppose to block any thread while it executes ([Great article about this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

By the way, because both your application and database are cloud based, it actually makes sense to look into `async` approach since both your application and you DB can scale.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's all three. There's network latency in sending the query/receiving the results. There's CPU-bound work when SQL Server or whatever is actually running the query against your database, and there's I/O as the database itself is a file on the filesystem.

However, from the perspective of your application, interacting with an external database via Entity Framework is network-bound, and is eligible for async as a result.

However, async is not a magical pill that will make your app run faster. If anything using async can actually *slow your application down*, as there's a lot of overhead to make async work. It's only purpose is to allow the thread doing work to return to the pool while it waits on some task outside of its control to finish. In the case of a database query, the query is sent off to the database which takes some period of time depending on network latency. The database must run the query and construct a result which takes some period of time depending on the resources available on that server. Then, the result is sent back to your application, which again incurs network latency. In a synchronous scenario, your application would just sit there and wait, holding onto the thread. In an async scenario, the thread is released to do other work (server other requests for the web server, etc.) and then when the database response is received the thread is requested back to finish whatever was going on in the application.

In case it's not obvious, the purpose of this is to allow the web server or whatever else you're working with to handle additional load by utilizing periods of what otherwise would be downtime doing other work. In that regard, async is important for using resources efficiently, but it's not necessarily quicker or more performant.

Comment: I do know most of this but thanks.  I have read that async can be slower in some circumstances but I am not clear in what cases that would be.  Keeping the thread pool available seems to be good, that is what all these Node.js enthusiasts are tell me.  I suppose I will have to code it and do some load tests.   I understand if these are just straight db calls then there is basically no gain, unless alot of people hit the website at once and threads get used up.

Comment: Ultimately, profiling is the only way to know for sure. Async is a bit of a micro-optimization, as you're not really going to see true benefit unless your web server hits its max requests (typically 1000 simultaneous requests). For most websites and applications that's *a lot*. Still, it's usually better to just go with async from the start, just in case you are ever blessed with so much traffic.